# Playing mp3 files in an audio element on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, html, audio

I am serving up .mp3 files via PHP and embedding them in the `audio` html5 element. I cannot get this to work for any iOS device (currently testing on iOS 9 on iPhone 6s). Basically when you press play it says "Live Broadcast" and no audio plays. If I try to download the file instead it opens up in to quicktime (I think) and also does nothing.

Here is how I serve the file

```
    $fileName = $queryParams['name'];
    $file = __DIR__ . "/../content/$fileName";    

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $len = filesize($file);
        $shortlen = $len - 1;
        header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$shortlen.'/'.$len);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3"); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

This is what it looks like in the browser developer tools

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=audiofile.mp3
Content-Length:12359460
Content-Range:bytes 0-12359459/12359460
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3
Date:Thu, 21 Dec 2017 17:14:57 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:public
Server:nginx/1.12.2
```

This is the HTML5

```
<audio controls="" preload="none" src="/content?name=audiofile.mp3"></audio>
```

The only information I get is this

> Failed (Plug-in handled load)

I have no idea what that means or what to do.

Comment: @J Doe. How did you get iOS to play an mp3 correctly?